# Please help me find the regex for the following pattern

Tags: regex

I want a regex pattern to find all the words of this format [xyzblab23la].

For example if the text has something like the following,

```
Lorem Ipsum dolor[32a] ameit[34]
```

I should be able to find the [32a] and [34]. Please tell me what is the regex for this pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following regex ***globally*** to find all the matches:

```
\[.*?\]
```

or

```
\[[^\]]*\]
```

Explanation:

- `\[` : `[` is a meta char for the
  start of the char class, so to match
  a literal `[` we need to escape it.
- `.*?` : match everything in a
  non-greedy way.
- `\]` : to match a literal `]`
- `[^\]]` : a char class that matches
  any char other than `]`
- `[^\]]*` : zero or more char of the
  above type.

Comment: Why have you stressed on the word 'globally'. Does that mean anything in regex world (i'm new to regex patterns)

Comment: Since you want to find *all* such patterns, we need to match the regex globally. By default (at least in Perl and in PHP-using preg_match) the matching process stops once it finds one match. In Perl we use the *g* option to the regex and in PHP we use the preg_match_all function to do the matching globally.

Answer (score 6):

Try this regular expression:

```
\[[^[\]]+]
```

A short explanation:

- `\[` matches a plain `[`
- `[^[\]]+` matches one or more arbitrary characters except `[` and `]`
- `]` matches a plain `]`

Answer (score 2):

```
/(\[[a-z0-9]+\])/i/
```